# Monthly magazine content organising

Tags: 7, nodes

I have to develop a monthly online magazine and I am looking for suggestions on the best way to organize the content.

Since it's a monthly publication, I want to organise content under **January**, for example. **January** will have multiple **articles**, **advertisements** etc all of which are nodes.

When time moves on to February, I want to unpublish January and consequently unpublish all the nodes associated with it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to publish or unpublished the content you should use Scheduler (http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) with this module let you to say when is publish the content and when will be unpublished.

To group the content, also you can build a field data (year-mounth) and use views to show a block with all the nodes with the same field-data, it should work like books block.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer next thing, you can create a taxonomy`vocabulary`  with months, and to unpublish nodes, you can do next thing:

1. Query to db to find nodes with taxonomy term inside(for example January)
2. Load node with `node_load`
3. Set the `$node->status = 0`
4. and save the node with `node_save`

This will unpublish all nodes with that month. About `associated nodes` - can say for sure, how they accosiated with a node?
Probably you will need to write your own module.

Comment: Thanks. By association I just meant that the articles should list under the relevant month.